# force decimalformat to format numbers in English not Arabic

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I'm using decimalFormat.format( 25.0 ) to remove trailing zero from a Double variable , however when I change my phone language into Arabic , numbers also change into Arabic. How can I keep them as English numbers ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the font of the textView to english. Create an asset folder. In that make a sub-folder called "fonts" and put the desired english font in that folder. Here is an example for arial font.

```
Typeface engFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(engFont);
```

Comment: this is not correct answer, because the problem in question may not be used in textView, but used elsewhere like file, webview, etc. etc.